# How to add Delay timer in C

Tags: c, time, timer

How do i write **C** code so that it waits 1 second or other specified duration **before going to the next line?**

for example: 
i want to create a stopwatch

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int Time  = 60;
 while(Time>=0){
    printf(Time);
  Time--;
} //i want my code to wait another second before execution of next line/loop
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for unix you can use the `sleep` function in  `<unistd.h>` which takes in an integer argument for the number of seconds to sleep 
for windows you can use the `Sleep` function in `<windows.h>` which takes in an integer argument for the number of milliseconds to sleep